# Looking for a DRY method of doing this animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to make a DRY version of this animation that I want to be looped into infinity. What should I look up to do this?

```
//fadeout
setTimeout(function(){$(".foot").fadeTo(1000, 0);}, 4000);
//change src
setTimeout(function(){$(".foot").attr("src","foot.png")}, 5000);
//fade in
setTimeout(function(){$(".foot").fadeTo(1000, 1)},6000)


setTimeout(function(){$(".foot").fadeTo(1000, 0);}, 10000);
//change src
setTimeout(function(){$(".foot").attr("src","follow.png")}, 11000);
//fade in
setTimeout(function(){$(".foot").fadeTo(1000, 1)},12000)
```

Comment: Wrap that code into a function. That will make it DRY as a desert. ;-)

Comment: ... are the srcs in an array by any chance?

Comment: wow, you just helped me figure it out. THANKS A BUNCH!

Comment: Gabe, can you explain what you want a little bit more? Maybe there are other things that will make it better. For example, do you have only two srcs that you want to alternate between them? Do you want this to stop or just loop back from the begining when it reaches the end?

Comment: That kind of animation should really be done with CSS and not jQuery. You will get much better performance and it will use the GPU rather than the CPU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The animation timing can be achieved by CSS [`@keyframes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes).

The image replacement on [`animationIteration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/animationiteration) event can be achieved with jQuery.

That is the most *"DRY"* that can be.

```js
// An array for the two images to toggle from
images = [
  "https://static.turbosquid.com/Preview/2014/07/03__20_05_28/foot_render_vray_1200x1200_001_main_image.jpg4ff0282c-0d04-4397-a6e0-855b6c0ec9f9Original.jpg",
  "https://content.marketearlybird.com/UploadedContent/Images/Follow%20Button%20Tick.png"
];

//  On animation iteration, change image.
$(".foot").on("webkitAnimationiteration oAnimationiteration msAnimationiteration animationiteration",function(){
  index = ($(this).attr("src") == images[0]) ? 1 : 0;
  $(this).attr("src",images[index]);
});
```

```css
.foot{
  width:200px;
  animation-name: fadeInOut;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes fadeInOut {
  0%{opacity: 0}
  50%{opacity: 1}
  100%{opacity: 0}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img class="foot" src="https://static.turbosquid.com/Preview/2014/07/03__20_05_28/foot_render_vray_1200x1200_001_main_image.jpg4ff0282c-0d04-4397-a6e0-855b6c0ec9f9Original.jpg">
```

Comment: This should really be marked as the correct answer because it is the DRY-est, most efficient way of doing it, and because it uses CSS keyframes you get a more performant animation.

Answer (score 1):

You can always try to use [`setInterval`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){$(".foot").fadeTo(1000, 0);}, 4000);
  setTimeout(function(){$(".foot").attr("src","foot.png")}, 5000);
  setTimeout(function(){$(".foot").fadeTo(1000, 1)},6000)
  setTimeout(function(){$(".foot").fadeTo(1000, 0);}, 10000);
  setTimeout(function(){$(".foot").attr("src","follow.png")}, 11000);
  setTimeout(function(){$(".foot").fadeTo(1000, 1)},12000)
}, 13000);
```

if you want the loop to stop write:

```
clearInterval(interval)
```